# Java, Jersey, xml substitution for @Path annotation

Tags: java, xml, rest, configuration

I have a project with RESTful services

Root classes must use @Path("/mylink") annotation

But I need to make some different ears with the same war, and path for root classes must be different

Best way I think - to have some xml file and place "/mylink" there. Via maven profiles I would change this string

I googled for an hour, but can't find the solution. Anyone help please.

P.S. Of cource I can make a lot of wrappers each with it's own path, but it's not a good solution I think.

Comment: I'm not sure what the exact problem you're trying to solve is.  Is it that you don't want `/x` to try to go to both wars?  Why don't you give each war a different context root to solve that problem?

Comment: I have one war and two ear. War contains, for example, one class. Path to this class must be different in ears

Comment: Yes, and you define the contextRoot in the ear, not in the wars.  It's not clear **why** you are trying to do this.

Comment: I define contextRoot for webmodule in ear, right. Also I need to define path to bean via annotation. And my path will be: ip:port/webmodulepath/beanpath .  I'm looking for a way to change second string - path to bean - at compile time.